# How do I display a copyright symbol in an email footer without gmail clipping the email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, copyright-display

I have tried just pasting in the symbol ©

I have also tried all of these: `&#169;` `&#xA9;` `&copy;`

Even a very short email is clipped as soon as I add this. The symbol always displays fine, but the email says that it is clipped even though no content is hidden.

I am sending emails with rails with ActionMailer through SendGrid.